# how to set my template on top of div a image with contant

Tags: events

Here's [a link](http://mydata.net23.net/screenshot-%7bdomain%7d%20%7bdate%7d%20%7btime%7d.png)!.
vist the image you will got my problem

Comment: these are starting from bottom i want them to start from top

Comment: Please include your code in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying the `vertical-align: top` CSS property on your cards.